# can't find any symbol in common lisp in emacs with slime

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, slime

According to the guide on the Internet, we can search in the HyperSpec for the symbol like "format" in emacs by typing C-c C-d h , However, I just cannot have it work, emacs just prompts that there's no completion for the symbol. Can somebody cope with it? thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have slime installed and loaded?  What is the result of doing `M-x hyperspec-lookup`?

Comment: it still prints "no match" after I press Enter:-(

Comment: What is the result of `C-h v common-lisp-hyperspec-root`? You probably need to put something like `(setq common-lisp-hyperspec-root "file:///usr/share/doc/hyperspec/")`in your .emacsrc

Answer (score 4):

Are you actually using the Slime REPL mode? Sometimes, when starting Slime without any configuration, you're not getting the REPL mode, and instead you'll be sitting in the `*inferior-lisp*` buffer.

First of all, check what the title of the buffer is. If it's `*inferior-lisp*`, it's not the correct one. It should read `*slime-repl sbcl*` (where sbcl refers to the CL implementation you're using).

If this is the case, then you need to make sure you enable slime-fancy in your Emacs init file. This is what I have:

```
(defun init-slime-configuration ()
  (slime-setup '(slime-fancy slime-fuzzy))
  (setq slime-load-failed-fasl 'never)
  (define-key slime-repl-mode-map (kbd "C-<tab>") 'slime-fuzzy-complete-symbol)
  (define-key slime-mode-map (kbd "C-<tab>") 'slime-fuzzy-complete-symbol))

(add-hook 'slime-load-hook 'init-slime-configuration)
```

This also allows me to use C-TAB for fuzzy expand.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this very problem after switching from the version of SLIME installed using Quicklisp (version 2.9) to that installed from MELPA (version 20141010.1357, as a dependency of ac-slime).

Using SLIME from Quicklisp worked fine with my local copy of the HyperSpec, using the settings:

```
(require 'slime-autoloads)
(add-to-list 'slime-contribs 'slime-fancy)
(setq slime-lisp-implementations
  '((ccl ("ccl"))
    (clisp ("clisp"))
    (cmucl ("cmucl"))
    (ecl ("ecl"))
    (sbcl ("sbcl"))))
(setq slime-default-lisp 'sbcl)
(setq common-lisp-hyperspec-root "file:/usr/share/doc/HyperSpec/")
(setq common-lisp-hyperspec-symbol-table "file:/usr/share/doc/HyperSpec/Data/Map_Sym.txt")
```

I then completely removed and reinstalled Quicklisp (without reinstalling SLIME!), then installed ac-slime from MELPA using the Emacs package manager.

By chance I happened to notice that when I tried to lookup documentation in the HyperSpec, Emacs opened a hidden buffer with an empty file named "Map_Sym.txt" in it.

Looking at the full pathname of this file using `C-h v buffer-file-name [RET]` revealed that it was set to "/home/miki/file:/usr/share/doc/HyperSpec/Data/Map_Sym.txt".

As an experiment, I tried removing the "file:/" from the last two lines of my settings, to make them read:

```
(setq common-lisp-hyperspec-root "/usr/share/doc/HyperSpec/")
(setq common-lisp-hyperspec-symbol-table "/usr/share/doc/HyperSpec/Data/Map_Sym.txt")
```

It appears to have resolved the issue. Why this works, I don't know (it differs from the documentation). A bug or undocumented change, maybe?